# Room ventilation during summer

Tags: pressure, air

I can never get this right =)
I have a main living room with air con running in summer. But CO2 levels build up.
Now its evening and I want to vent the room but without the room getting too hot again (its still 39C outside)
Do I open the door in the same room as air con or the door in the opposite side of the house or both?
The way I understand it is that cold air should flow to the outside. But how does the fresh air come back in? Only after pressure is equalized?

Comment: Google for "Heat Recovery Ventilator" or "Energy Recovery Ventilator." They're commercially available, counter-current heat exchangers that are designed either to be plumbed in to your home's HVAC system or, to be fitted to a single room. With a heat recovery ventilator, you can run your AC _and_ have fresh air all day long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing is that the thermal capacity of air is quite low. So what you want to do is exchanging the air in the room as quickly as possible as completely as possible. You'll than have warm air inside but this will quickly be cooled down again by the still cold walls, furniture and everything else in your house.
So it's up to you to plan where you want the air to come in and where it has to go out to exchange the air in the house effectively. Opening windows/doors on two sides of the house is the most efficient way in many cases. Just letzt the air go trough 5-10 minutes and you're probably good. To get it more precisely you'd have to measure and test different approaches (a smoke machine can be of great help to see where air is "standing").